# Subset Data Frame to Exclude 28 Different Months in R Using dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a data frame consisting of monthly volumes beginning 2004-01-01 and ending 2019-12-01. I need to apply a filter that will delete rows that equal certain dates. My problem is that there's 28 dates I need to filter out and they arent consecutive. What I have right now works, but isn't efficient. I am using dplyr's filter function.

I currently have 28 variables, d1-d28, which are the dates that I would like filtered out and then I use

```
df<-data%>%dplyr::filter(Date!=d1 & Date!=d2 & Date!=d3 .......Date!=d28)
```

I would like to put the dates of interest, the d1-d28, into a data.frame and just reference the data.frame in my filter code.

I've tried:

```
df<-data%>%dplyr::filter(!Date %in% DateFilter)
```

Where DateFilter is a data.frame with 1 column and 28 rows of the dates I want filtered, but I get an an error where it says the length of the objects don't match.

Is there any way I can do this with dplyr?

Comment: What is `DateFilter`

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear the DateFilter is a data.frame with the dates I would like filtered. (1 column, 28 rows)

Comment: You need to transform it into a vector to use with %in%--do something like `DateFilter$col_name` or `dplyr::pull(DateFilter, col_name)`.
Also it's immensely helpful to provide a sample of your data (both the df data and DataFilter) so these things are clear. `dput` is useful to create copiable structures.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we may use `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
      filter_at(vars(matches('^d\\d+$')), all_vars(Date != .))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you clarify what `'^d\\d+$'` is means/doing? I ran the code and got an error saying Error:`.predicate has no matching columns`

Comment: @a_js12 In your post, you showed `d1`, `d2` etc as column names, right?

Comment: No they are values, but when put into a data.frame they are rows

Comment: @a_js12 Can you please update your post with an example as It is not clear